# MySQL Query to Select All and Convert Date

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

How would I write a query in MySQL to select all and to convert 2 UNIX date columns to something readable, i.e. - from_unixtime(received_date) without needing to manually write out each of the other column names in my select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT *, from_unixtime(received_date), from_unixtime(other_date_field) FROM table;
```

You will have your two date columns shown in both time stamp and readable formats in the result. You might want to use AS to rename the readable columns like so:

```
SELECT *, from_unixtime(received_date) AS date1, from_unixtime(other_date_field) AS date2 FROM table;
```

Note that the wild card has to come first:

```
SELECT *, field FROM...
```

You'll get an error if you do SELECT field, * FROM...

I hope this helps.